# GIT: Why use master (or any branch) as to reflect what's in production

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

We're having a debate here on our server development team, and I'm struggling. I've always used master as source of record for production, with the master branch (or some designated release branch) acting as a long-running release branch. I'm in favor of using GitFlow for our process, releasing from master and tagging the releases, but right now, all I have is instinct and past experiences.

I'm not specifically looking for someone to tell me "this process is better than that process", but instead, to provide some evidence as to *why* a long-running branch (like master) plus tagged releases is a good (or a bad) thing. Does anyone have any specific evidence that it's better or worse than short-running release branches with tags on the short running ones?

*edit*: Information was requested about our development process: We're actually in flux right now. We've just migrated from SVN to GIT, and are in the process of decomposing a monolith into microservices (or at least decomposed monoliths). Essentially, we support multiple deployment environments, with a clone of each acting as an integration environment, and a development environment independent of the integration environment. The development teams verify work in the local environment and that gets pushed to integration for testing, then services get deployed to production from there. We currently have over 500 services in the monolith, and will likely end up with ~300+ separate microservices or so. Coupled with the dependency projects, we will likely end up with around 600+ separate git projects when we're all finished.

Comment: I'm afraid even asking for evidence will still produce opinion based answers to this question. Even if there is evidence, the question as it stands is too broad without knowing more about the development process your team uses.

Comment: We're actually in flux right now. We've just migrated from SVN to GIT, and are in the process of decomposing a monolith into microservices (or at least decomposed monoliths). Essentially, we support multiple deployment environments, with a clone of each acting as an integration environment, and a development environment independent of the integration environment. The development teams verify work in the local environment and that gets pushed to integration for testing, then services get deployed to production from there.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. It is too difficult to find this info in a comment.

Comment: I don't understand this question. So long as you deploy to production from some branch, you have a branch (whatever it's named) that reflects what's in production. Unless you do something silly like develop in production. I always put a note in the git log when we release. It's the same commit that changes the version number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the master branch as the canonical source for code in production makes it easier for developers to clone the repository and immediately have production code in front of them. It's as simple as:

```
git clone your-repo
```

If a different branch is used for production code, then the master branch still needs to represent *something*, otherwise it will cause confusion.

I worked on a project where we had a development branch (literally called "development") and then created a release branch from that. The master branch became this weird no-man's land of code that people forgot to update. This was annoying, because I was constantly reminding people — experienced team members  included — that they needed to check out the `development` branch or a release branch.

Making it easy to clone the repository and see production code is basically the only reason. Otherwise just decide what "master" represents and stick with it, as long as you avoid the no-man's land situation I had, where "master" was never really used.

Comment: It sounds like a large part of the issue here would have been solved by simply deleting the `master` branch if it didn't have any use, and setting `development` as  the default branch of the repo.

Comment: “If a different branch is used for production code, then the master branch still needs to represent something, otherwise it will cause confusion.” It represents the latest shared history that everyone bases their new work on. That was its original purpose.

Comment: @Guildenstern: Greg's point is that in that particular project, it actually did *not* represent the latest shared history that everyone bases their new work on - there was a different branch that did that instead.

Answer (score 4):

Well, how else do you know what’s in prod? Download the live copy and recursive diff? Guess? Etc.?

In other words, it provides a useful comparison point and a useful assumption about whats live (though it is helpful to regularly check this assumption, which git fetch + some plumbing can easily show).

Comment: The alternate solution is to create a release branch for testing, then tag the release branch when going to production. The release branch is shortly-used (but kept around) though, and only used until it is deployed. It would stick around for eternity as a record of what was / is deployed.

Comment: Well, that could be a relevant question detail

Comment: @RobertK I think you should edit the info on the alternate solution into your question.  The difference that I can see is if you need to support multiple releases at the same time (e.g you have customers on v3 and v4) then having a release branch is necessary, as you will provide fixes for v3 on the v3 release branch, and fixes for v4 on the v4 release branch.  Company I worked at had about 3 or 4 active releases at time and used that structure.

Comment: >  know what’s in prod?

You look at the record made when code was deployed to prod. Hopefully your deployments are automated, so each deployment should be recorded somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit is if you want a stable name for “latest
release”. That’s it.

You might just need to know what the latest version is. Maybe you don’t
need a moving pointer named “master” or “production” or something like
that.

If you do want it then you can use a branch that fast-forwards to
whatever the latest “production” commit is. But keep in mind: if people
don’t end up needing that name then they might just end up forgetting to
update it.

(Let me quickly check what commit `master` is on at my job… oh, it’s the
initial commit. We use a branch called `develop` as the main branch. We have no other eternal branches.)

Every release to production will probably get its own version tag
(git-tag(1)). Or at the very minimum it will be associated with the
commit it was built on (like with git-describe(1)). I would also prefer
if every build on remote test installations (which are totally *ad hoc*)
are also marked in such a way that we know what commit it was built on,
because we want to know what code tree it was that produced a given
stacktrace. (Same goes for production of course.)

Now let’s say you have five recent versions and you have fifteen
different customers who are all on one of them, because

1. Some version was made for one single customer so you didn’t need to
   update all of them
2. Some version was deemed pretty safe for one product line but not for
   another one so deploying to those other customers was put on hold
   until a later release
3. You wanted to upgrade customer A and B and needed a signoff from a
   contact person at each one but one of the contact persons had taken
   an early weekend and it’s Friday 13:00

What have you gained from the fact that your branch `master` (or `release` or `production`…) is
effectively a synonym for Git tag `154.56.6` (the latest version)?

Comment: Some of this answer gets a bit distracted by the *name* `master`, rather than the *concept* of "some designated release branch". For instance, it's not really relevant that you have a dead branch called `master` in your repo; you might still have a branch called "release" or "production" or "gold" that serves the purpose outlined in the question. The other parts of the answer about it not being useful in environments where there are multiple production deployments is more relevant.

Comment: @IMSoP I don’t really think it fixates on “master” given that I start the post with “stable name for “latest release”” and then in the next paragraph say ““master” or “production”” (as in: whatever name you have). It’s like the “default branch”: it gets a bit tedious to say “master or main or whatever your default branch name is”. But I’ll update the answer a bit. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: @IMSoP “you might still have a branch”—Good point. We don’t have any other eternal branches than `develop`. I’ve edited that in now. Thanks.